# How can I see which system update Android wants to install?

Tags: updates, operating-system, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I use a Samsung Galaxy S23 ultra with Android 13 and One 5.1. I see:

[image]

How can I see which system update Android wants to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The update information on Samsung One UI can only be seen from the "Download and install" menu.**

[image]